# Replace a QScrollArea's layout with a new one

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, qscrollarea

I've written a program that builds a GUI using PyQt. From Qt Designer, I have a MainWindow, a QTabWidget inside that, and a QScrollArea inside the QTabWidget. I'm trying to dynamically build a list of matches with match data, add each match to a widget's layout, and put this layout in the QScrollArea. Currently, my code does this perfectly, except it raises the following error:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
```

This makes sense to me, but I don't understand how to fix it. I'm not really even sure how what I have does what it does, either, which makes it harder to fix.

Inside of my MainWindow `__init__()` method, I make an instance of the MatchHistoryBuilder class (which builds each match), call a buildMatchHistory() method (which is in the MainWindow class), and pass it that instance of MatchHistoryBuilder, like this:

```
matchHistoryBuilder = MatchHistoryBuilder(self)
self.buildMatchHistory(matchHistoryBuilder)
```

Here is my buildMatchHistory method:

```
def buildMatchHistory(self, matchHistoryBuilder):
        # This method takes whatever matches are in match_history.txt, calls MatchHistoryBuilder.buildMatch() on each, 
        # and builds the GUI objects for the match history into the matchHistoryScrollArea.
        # Globals: self.mainWindow

        # Open match_history.txt and read json data into matchHistoryData
        fileLocation = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
        fileLocation = fileLocation + '\match_history.txt'
        with open(fileLocation,  'r') as f:
            matchHistoryData = json.load(f)
        matchHistoryData = matchHistoryData["matches"]

        # Scroll Area Properties
        matchHistory = self.ui.matchHistoryScrollArea
        matchHistory.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        matchHistory.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # Container Widget       
        widget = QWidget()
        # Layout of Container Widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for matchIndex, matchInstance in enumerate(matchHistoryData):
            matchId = matchInstance["matchId"]
            match = matchHistoryBuilder.buildMatch(summonerId, matchIndex, matchId)
            layout.addWidget(match)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        matchHistory.setWidget(widget)
```

MatchHistoryBuilder.buildMatch() returns a QGroupBox correctly.

How can I make this method correctly build each match object, add them to a QVBoxLayout, and add that QVBoxLayout to my QScrollArea?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the `QVBoxLayout`, don't give it `self` (the MainWindow) as the parent

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
```

Passing a parent to a `QLayout` will automatically make it the top-level layout for that widget.